# Add direct link to email beside button

Tags: email

When I am creating HTML email with call to action button, should I add direct URL for copy/paste to address bar beside clickable button? Is there any reason to use this "fallback" in 2021?

Example:

> Hi, please click button below to visit our site.
>
> [clickable button]
>
> If you have any trouble, copy this URL:
>
> https://example.com/some/url?with=variousParameters

Answer (score 1):

For call to action (CTA) buttons and links in emails, there are two perspectives I would consider:

#### Ease of use

Usually users will seek the easiest way, hence click on a hyperlink where possible instead of triplet select-copy-paste.

#### Transparency & Trust

On the other side an explicitly made transparent URL could convey a sense of security. Some users may suspect a malicious hyperlink like in phishing mails, etc.
They will definitely first check the given "non-hyperlinked" URL (i.e. WYSIWYG) for plausibility. Then this plain URL could establish additional trust in your mail and the referenced target.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors here:

1. It depends on who is your user and what is that company doing. Some security-minded users don't load images in their email client and they might need to be able to click that link.
2. Does the user need to login to access that page after he clicks the button in your email? If the answer is yes, I would still add the link below for security reasons.
3. Is the email you're sending a marketing campaign? Don't add it, no major security risk there.